# what is the "JVMTI_ERROR_NONE"?

Tags: java, jvm

Sometimes the following error message (screenshot attached below) is shown when I run my code.
But every thing will be OK after I re-run.
Who knows why? Thanks.

msg screenshot:
[image: error msg]

The version is:

```
java version "1.8.0" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7142035.

The bug is described as fixed in Java 9, and the fix has been backported to Java 8 and Java 7.  We can't say much more than what the bug report says.

Solution: upgrade.

(The build numbers you need are in the bug report, but upgrading to "the latest" builds of Java 7 or 8, or any version/build of Java after 8 should be sufficient.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer~   I'm using jdk 1.8 but still this bug appears. It didn't seem to affect the results, I'm just curious why, hahh.

Comment: 1) Which update / build of Java 8 are you using? 2) It might be a different bug.

Comment: java version "1.8.0" ||| 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132) ||| 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

Comment: OK ... so according to that the bug report, that build of Java 8 should have the fix back-ported.  However, you should upgrade anyway.  The current version is u281.  There are a bazzilion fixes between u132 and u281 ... including some important security fixes.  (Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8 and open up the Java 8 updates table ...)

Comment: OK, Thx a lot Stephen!